# rails generate ckeditor:install could not load generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor, rails-generate

I added to the Gemfile

`gem 'ckeditor'`

also I tried to add

`gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git'`

or

`gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git', :branch =>'rails3'`

Bundle install is successfuly complete, but when I call in project directory the command

`rails g ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip`

I get the following response

> [WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/ckeditor/install_generator". Error: uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Rails::Generators.
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/ckeditor-6d8032b87595/lib/generators/ckeditor/install_generator.rb:6:in `<module:Generators>'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/ckeditor-6d8032b87595/lib/generators/ckeditor/install_generator.rb:5:in`'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/ckeditor-6d8032b87595/lib/generators/ckeditor/install_generator.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:300:in`block (2 levels) in lookup'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:296:in `each'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:296:in`block in lookup'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:295:in `each'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:295:in`lookup'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:152:in `find_by_namespace'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:169:in`invoke'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
>   /home/boberobor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in`'
>   script/rails:6:in `require'
>   script/rails:6:in`'
>   Could not find generator ckeditor:install.

What's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The issue was in the Gemfile. There is

`gem 'rails-ckeditor'`

in it.

Perhaps, there were any conflicts. I deleted this line, run bundle and generator is performed.